# Tkinter will not refresh after a button was pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
import tkinter
import random
from random import randint
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.constants import CENTER, COMMAND, X
from typing import Coroutine
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import os
import hashlib
import asyncio


CurrentCode = None
standbyMessage= "Enter Code"
correctHash = [REDACTED]

async def correctCode():
    global CodeDisplay
    i = 5
    while i > 0:
        CodeDisplay.config(text = f'DOOR OPEN\n{i}')
        time.sleep(1)
        i -= 1
    pass

def keyPressed(k):
    global CurrentCode
    if CurrentCode == None:
        CurrentCode = k
    else:
        if len(str(CurrentCode)) < 4:
            CurrentCode = (f'{CurrentCode}{k}')
    print(CurrentCode)
    inputChanged()

def inputChanged():
    global CodeDisplay
    global CurrentCode
    global correctHash
    global standbyMessage
    CodeDisplay.config(text = f"{CurrentCode}")
    if CurrentCode == None:
        CodeDisplay.config(text=standbyMessage)


def checkCode():
    global CodeDisplay
    global CurrentCode
    hashed = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', str(CurrentCode).encode('utf-8'), b'\x8f\xd0\xc11i\xd64\x9c\xe6?\x0eE\xa4\x0e>\x88\xa0G\xb2\x1e<M\x93\xf4\x1c\xdca\x1b\xd0\xd3!\xef', 1000000)
    print(hashed)
    if hashed == correctHash:
        correctCode()
    clear()



def clear():
    global CurrentCode
    CurrentCode = None
    inputChanged()
async def main():
    global root
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("TestApp1")
    root.geometry("300x600")
    root.attributes("-topmost",True)
    #root.config(cursor="none")
    global CodeDisplay
    CodeDisplay = tkinter.Label(root, text= standbyMessage)
    CodeDisplay.place(y=60,x=150,anchor=CENTER)

    tkinter.Button(root, text="1", command=lambda: keyPressed(1),background="grey",foreground="white").place(x=45,width=90,y=120,height=60,anchor=CENTER)
    tkinter.Button(root, text="2", command=lambda: keyPressed(2),background="grey",foreground="white").place(x=150,width=90,y=120,height=60,anchor=CENTER)
    tkinter.Button(root, text="3", command=lambda: keyPressed(3),background="grey",foreground="white").place(x=255,width=90,y=120,height=60,anchor=CENTER)

    tkinter.Button(root, text="4", command=lambda: keyPressed(4),background="grey",foreground="white").place(x=45,width=90,y=200,height=60,anchor=CENTER)
    tkinter.Button(root, text="5", command=lambda: keyPressed(5),background="grey",foreground="white").place(x=150,width=90,y=200,height=60,anchor=CENTER)
    tkinter.Button(root, text="6", command=lambda: keyPressed(6),background="grey",foreground="white").place(x=255,width=90,y=200,height=60,anchor=CENTER)

    tkinter.Button(root, text="7", command=lambda: keyPressed(7),background="grey",foreground="white").place(x=45,width=90,y=280,height=60,anchor=CENTER)
    tkinter.Button(root, text="8", command=lambda: keyPressed(8),background="grey",foreground="white").place(x=150,width=90,y=280,height=60,anchor=CENTER)
    tkinter.Button(root, text="9", command=lambda: keyPressed(9),background="grey",foreground="white").place(x=255,width=90,y=280,height=60,anchor=CENTER)

    tkinter.Button(root, text="*", command=lambda: clear(),background="grey",foreground="white").place(x=45,width=90,y=360,height=60,anchor=CENTER)
    tkinter.Button(root, text="0", command=lambda: keyPressed(0),background="grey",foreground="white").place(x=150,width=90,y=360,height=60,anchor=CENTER)
    tkinter.Button(root, text="#", command=lambda: checkCode,background="grey",foreground="white").place(x=255,width=90,y=360,height=60,anchor=CENTER)


    root.mainloop()
```

The problem I'm having is in the correctCode() method, I try to make a countdown after my hash was correctly matched but the text label does not update until the system asks for a code again. I believe this can be fixed with asyncio but then the user is able to enter more characters even when the checkCode() method is running, I am honestly stumped on what to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loops I suggest using [`.after()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/)(also more universal) because using a loop like `while` will interfere with tkinters `mainloop()` and if it is not reached it won't update [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label


def loop(number):
    if number < 0:
        return
    lbl.config(text=f'{number}')
    root.after(10, loop, number - 1)


root = Tk()

lbl = Label(root, text='')
lbl.pack()

loop(1000)

root.mainloop()
```

In Your case You could put `loop(5)` so it loops 5 times or sth like that
To mention `.after(time_in_ms, func, args)` somewhere was something about how to add kwargs but...

Another method is to use `root.update()`(not suggested because it can cause other issues):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label


def loop(number):
    for i in range(number):
        lbl.config(text=f'{i}')
        root.update()


root = Tk()

lbl = Label(root, text='')
lbl.pack()

loop(10000)

root.mainloop()
```